# Leaflet EasyButton MouseOver event

Tags: javascript, leaflet, easybutton-plugin

I am using [easybutton](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton) plugin for [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/). Is there a possibility to display an image+some text when mouse is over on the button?

Here is my current code:

```
 var btn2 = L.easyButton ({position: 'topright', 
  states: [{
    stateName: 'NoSources2',
    icon:'<img src=ico/closed_eye.png height="16" width="16"><span>   masquer le nombre de resources</span>',
      title: 'NoSources' ,
      onClick: function(control) {
                map.removeLayer(NoSources);
                control.state('NoSources1')},
    },
    {
     stateName: 'NoSources1',
    icon: '<img src=ico/oeil.jpg height="16" width="16"><span>   voir le nombre de resources</span>',
    title: 'NoSources',
    onClick: function(control)  {
    map.addLayer(NoSources);
    control.state('NoSources2')}, 
  }]
});
btn2.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following describes a method for a mouseover image for an easybutton.

(1)  Add an id to your easybutton:

```
var btn2 = L.easyButton ({position: 'topright', id:'sbut',
```

(2) Add event listeners to your button which call the mover and mout functions:

```
document.getElementById("sbut").addEventListener("mouseover", mover);
document.getElementById("sbut").addEventListener("mouseout", mout);
```

(3) Add to your HTML an image, substituting in the image {IMGURL}:

```
<div class "container">
    <div class "picture">
        <img alt="n e image" id="neimage" style="display: none" src="{IMGURL}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

(4) create the function *mover* to display the image at mouse coords; note as your button is top right then the image width is subtracted to get it to display with the NE corner at mouse position:

```
function mover(event){
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;    
    var img = document.getElementById('neimage');
    img.style.display = '';
    img.style.position = 'fixed';
    img.style.left = x - img.width + 'px';
    img.style.top = y + 'px';    
    img.style.zIndex = 1000;
    }
```

(5) create the function *mout* which will remove the displayed image when the mouse leaves the button:

```
function mout (event){
    document.getElementById('neimage').style.display = 'none';
}
```

**References**

[display image position based on mouse click coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33816006/display-image-position-based-on-mouse-click-coordinates)

[addeventlistener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover_addeventlistener)

[image dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633264/javascript-get-image-dimensions)

[image z index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Thank you for extensive explanation, but I could not make it worked out. In case I am missing a point: is it something you already tested in some work? @JimT

Comment: yes - tested as working in Chrome. Have you tried checking the console for error messages?